# Sublime-text command as keybinding

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I want to add a keybinding for Reindent(Edit>Line>Reindent).

I have tried adding

```
"keys": ["ctrl+shift+i"], "command": "reindent"
```

But this does nothing even after restarting sublime

Other answers seems to be outdated.

Full Settings-User file:

```
// Settings in here override those in "Default/Preferences.sublime-settings",
// and are overridden in turn by file type specific settings.
{
    "update_check":false,
    "font_size":11,
    {"keys": ["ctrl+shift+i"], "command": "reindent"},
}
```

Comment: Forgot curly brackets around the statement? `{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+i"], "command": "reindent"},`

Comment: @smc No, that gives me `Error trying to parse settings: Expected value in Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings:6:2`

Comment: Can you post full example? more than just one line. Also, which file are you editing?

Comment: @smc added the entire file in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are adding the config to the wrong file. It has to go into `Key Bindings - User` , not in the `Settings - User`.

Also you don't need the comma at the end of the last line in the list.

According to the information you have provided, here is what I recommend:

Edit the contents of your `Settings - User` to the following:

```
// Settings in here override those in "Default/Preferences.sublime-settings",
// and are overridden in turn by file type specific settings.
{
    "update_check":false,
    "font_size":11
}
```

Edit the contents of your `Key Bindings - User` to the following:

```
[
    {"keys": ["ctrl+shift+i"], "command": "reindent"}
]
```

Note, if you want to always reindent the entire contents of the open file regardless the selection you can edit your `Key Bindings - User` to the following:

```
[
    {"keys": ["ctrl+shift+i"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false}}
]
```

Comment: Worked great, and now I feel like an idiot for not seeing the key-bindings file haha. Thanks mate!